# Move to Focus selected class file project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

In eclipse, i've opened more class from different project.

When i click any class , the appropriate project focused and moved on left side package explore.

Now its not working.. How to enable this function on eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a two way arrow button [above the package explorer](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=eclipse%20link%20package%20explorer%20to%20class&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=EKHOUeH6F8rEtQbDmYGQBA&biw=1280&bih=923&sei=EqHOUfKUFYLTswbq24GYCw#facrc=_&imgrc=3-jczihv4RDLWM%3a;ED7KMGZGnwEiSM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.vogella.com%252Farticles%252FEclipse%252Fimages%252Feditorsyncpackage10.png;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.vogella.com%252Farticles%252FEclipse%252F;870;711).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure "Link with Editor" is selected in the Project/Package explorer.

[image]